# I am implementing mix color into excels cell using PHPExcel, reflecting color changes into open-office but not reflecting into microsoft-office o

Tags: php, phpexcel

**I am implementing mix color into excels cell text using PHPExcel library, reflecting color changes into open-office but not reflecting into microsoft-office:**

My Code Snippet (Just part of code):

```
<?php
....
$objRichText_cell_E = new PHPExcel_RichText();
$objRichText_cell_E->createText('');
$objTopic1 = $objRichText_cell_E->createTextRun('Total # of Students');
$objTopic1->getFont()->getColor()->setRGB('004080'); 
$objTopic2 = $objRichText_cell_E->createTextRun('(Only Absent Students)');
$objTopic2->getFont()->getColor()->setRGB('ff0000');
$objTopic2->getFont()->setItalic(true);
$oExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('E'.$sheetCellCnt)->setValue($objRichText_cell_E);
.... 
?>
```

**Above script generating mix color in single excel sheet in open office, but this color changes are not reflecting into microsoft office.**

could you please suggest me changes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip following statement from your script:

$objRichText_cell_E->createText('');